# Is it possible to get an internal usb port into my notebook?

Tags: laptop, usb, motherboard, usb-hub

I have a special piece of hardware that I soldered together and I have built it into my notebook. The problem is: The device requires to be connected to the computer via USB. At the moment I have a USB cable soldered to it that leaves the notebook case on the bottom and goes into one of the external ports.

There are two problems though:
- There is a freaking cable coming out of the bottom of my notebook.
- The device uses one of the external USB ports. (I only have 3.)

I guess I could detach one of the USB ports internally and solder my hardware to the motherboard header or so... but again, there is still the problem that I would lose one of my USB ports.

So I'm wondering if there is some kind of Y adapter/hub for the ribbon cable that connects the USB port to the motherboard. (See where it says "USB board" on the photo)

Or would that only work on the other side of the USB board? :/

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the make and model of the laptop? Someone might be able to find the schematics for your mainboard. Why did you build the custom hardware *into* the laptop?

Comment: I built it into the laptop because I always use it when I use that laptop and I don't want to have an additional device lying on my desk. It's an `HP Pavilion G6-2348SG`.

Comment: Take out the optical drive, connect a standard USB hub to the MB and shove it in that space, run one of the ports out of the case.

Comment: The space where the optical drive used to be is already taken by an HDD and my custom piece of hardware. And what do you mean by "run one of the ports out of the case"? I'd like to use the existing USB ports and I think it's really unlikely that I would find a good way of screwing one of the hub ports into the spot where the USB board is currently screwed in.

Comment: @Forivin, I am in a similar situation, and im interested if you happen to find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a solution. :/

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of USB hubs out there with all kinds of different hardware configuration packaging. From usb ports soldered on a pc board to loose wire usb packaging attached to a small box. Pick one you think might be usable for your situation and buy it. If you have to lose the packaging and form your own to fit it into your laptop, then sacrifices must be made. You can even copy what you find to make your own version of the hub using what's there. Of course you will have to give up an existing usb port in your laptop in order to connect the hub, but that should easily be compensated for, by one of the other hub ports that you are connecting; even if you have to relocate the port plug-in location on your laptop. Its really up to you how to do it based on how creative you are, and what you can live with. Just remember that you are changing the original configuration and design of your laptop, so don't expect it to be exactly the same. Everybody wants to change things and not have anything be different. Unfortunately nothing ever really works that way. And some changes can't be undone, so be sparing.